# Impersonate System.Environment.UserName in an asmx service

Tags: asmx

I created an asmx service which executes a python script. When I test it as localhost, I get the same `System.Environment.UserName` both in soap and in python script.

When I publish it, the `System.Environment.UserName` changes in pythonscript and it gets the PC name instead of the Windows user name.

This is a code snippet of how I execute the python script.

```
try
{
    using (new NetworkImpersonation.SoddingNetworkAuth("username", "localhost", "password"))
    {
        var serviceController = new ServiceController("Power", "localhost");

        if (serviceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            envuserName = System.Environment.UserName;

            insertVRP_Routing_Logs("testPy3", "EnvUSERNAME: " + envuserName, "USERNAME: " + userName, "SOAP_AFTER_IMPERS");
            start.FileName = "c:\\Progra~1\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\envs\\arcgispro-py3\\python.exe";
                            
            // pass these to arguments property of ProcessStartInfo instance
            start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\*******\\*****\\Toolboxes\\Py3_VRP_Solver_json_v7.py", jobID);
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Authenticated, service not running";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    result = "Authentication failed";
}

start.UseShellExecute = false;
//start.Verb = "runas";
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;

int result2 = -1;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Restart();

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {   
        // result = reader.ReadLine();
        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        result2 = process.ExitCode;

        // Console.Write(result);
    }
}

sw.Stop();
```

I have to mentioned that I tried impersonation with no success. Below is a capture of the logs:

[image]

Is there a way to keep in python script the same `System.Environment.UserName` as the one in asmx service?